# The randomly generated OTP for mobile verification is not updating to DB

Tags: php, mysql, mobile

I am working on a project where I have to verifiy the user's mobile number. I has generated the otp and its successfully deliver to users mobile. But the otp variable does not show any value in the update mysql query. while on echo it print the result.

Code is here:

```
if(isset($_POST['mobile']))
{
    include_once("connectionfile.php");
    $string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $string_shuffled = str_shuffle($string);
    $otpCode = substr($string_shuffled, 1, 7);
    echo '<br/>'. $otpCode;
    file_get_contents("http://www.sms99.com/ComposeSMS.aspx?username=sample&password=sample&sender=sample&to=$payMob&message=$password&priority=1&dnd=1&unicode=0");
    echo '</br>'.$otpCode;
    $optQry = "update clients set mobile='$payMob', address='$payAddress', city='$payCity', country='$payCountry', opt_code='$optCode' where id = '$payClient'" ;
    echo $optQry; 
    $qryRes = mysqli_query($con, $optQry)or die("query Error");
    print_r($optRes);
}
```

output screen:

> 1E2ewz7
>
> update clients set mobile='4422336699', address='new way',
>   city='fkldsjl', country='IN', opt_code='' where id = '131'

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have got a typo in your variable.

Change `$optCode` in `$optQry` to `$otpCode`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$optQry = "update clients set mobile='$payMob', address='$payAddress', city='$payCity', country='$payCountry', opt_code='$otpCode' where id = '$payClient'" ;
```

Comment: It is working.But where i was wrong I also has write the same query

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the exact same variable in your query please use the below :

`$optQry = "update clients set mobile='$payMob', address='$payAddress', city='$payCity', country='$payCountry', opt_code='$otpCode' where id = '$payClient'" ;`

just use `$otpCode` that's it.

please mark as correct if it helps.

Thanks